# Dynamic argument and Generic type

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I have following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test(data interface{}) {
    data = "123"
}

func main() {
    t := "org"
    test(&t)
    fmt.Println(t)

    e := 1
    test(&e)
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

I tried to add pointer to *interface{} but it throws errors, how can I assign string "test" to `t` when I print it? right now `t` will be printed out as "org"

I am asking because I am not sure how I can use dynamic type here, for instance, `josn.Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{})` I used this function, and it can convert databyte to any type we want as long as we pass the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are expecting `interface` to be much more magic than it actually is.

Consider this variant of your program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test(p *string) {
    s := "test"
    p = &s
}

func main() {
    t := "org"
    test(&t)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Do you expect this to print `test`?  If so, we have a bigger problem. :-)  If not, why do you expect the version with `p interface{}` to change `t` when assigning directly to `p`?

If we change `test` to write *through* `*p`:

```
func test(p *string) {
    *p = "test"
}
```

the program *does* print `test`, as you expected.

All that remains now is to handle the case when `p` is declared instead as `data interface{}`.  As in [bserdar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58277954/1256452), you must first extract the underlying `*string` pointer from the interface object in `data`.  You can then use that pointer to set `main`'s variable `t`.  You could do this with two steps:

```
func test(data interface{}) {
    p := data.(*string)
    *p = "test"
}
```

for instance, or you can do it all in one line.

Comment: Though, if you use this solution, the program will panic if `data` is not a `string`, in which case, the function *should* be `test(data string)` since that is what it expects as a parameter.

Comment: thank you for your replay,  I am using interface{}, because I like the argument to accept any possible type,  I saw `json.Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) ` function in the library, and it accepts all type and persist the pointer there, I am wondering how they implement it. I am new to Golang by the way. was Java developer

Comment: As Adrian (almost?) said, by using `interface{}`, you get an opportunity, in your function `test`, to inspect what type-and-value you actually got. Doing `data.(*string)` asserts—without first testing—that the type you got was `*string`. The compiler inserts a runtime type-check to see if that was true and if not, to call `panic`.

Comment: Typically, one would use `interface{}` if `test` should be able to handle, e.g., both `*string` and, say, `*int`. Then you would write `test` to *check* whether it got `*string` or `*int`, and do whatever you deem The Right Thing based on that. To be even more general—at a noticeable runtime cost—you can do what `json.Unmarshal` does and use the `reflect` package to inspect the interface value you got. The more general you make function `test`, the harder it is to write it and the more runtime code you need, so be sure the result is as valuable as the expense.

Comment: Note that if you just want to handle `*string` and `*int`, it's much easier—and compile-time safe—to write two separate functions, one that takes `*string` and one that takes `*int`. Generics, which let you get compile-time safety *and* type flexibility (at some compile-time cost), are coming in Go 2.

Comment: thank you for explaining! right, because my Java mindset,  I was wondering how Golang manage Generic type, I get the "reflect" part, since it's similar to "reflection" in Java

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the interface, not the underlying value. Instead you should do

```
func test(data interface{}){
  *data.(*string) = "aaa"
}
```

That is, first get the underlying string pointer, then set the string pointed by it.